# How to set database cluster arguments (like password) with terraform?

Tags: mysql, terraform, digital-ocean, provisioning

I deploy a `digitalocean_database_cluster` with Terraform. It's working and I can connect to it with the username and password that Terraform generates in .tfstate

I want to set a **concrete** username, password, and port. I'm reading the [DO documentation](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/terraform/reference/resources/database_cluster/), but I don't see these arguments, so:

Is my strategy wrong (can't force a concrete value) or there's another way/resource to this?

PS: I'm new to Terraform

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [digitalocean_database_user](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/terraform/reference/resources/database_user/) resource to provision a user with a concrete username, though you will still get an automatic password. It doesn't look like Digital Ocean lets you set a user password through their management API (which TF uses), so you'll need to change it using regular DB interaction.

Why do you want to set a custom port on the cluster?

Comment: Not especially needed. But I want to understand why some values are not settable on resource provisioning.
What do you mean by regular DB interaction? Is this out of Terraform's definition? Like a script that I have to execute after resource creation?

Comment: I assume the port is not settable simply because there's no reason to use any port other than the standard - the cluster is not going to be running multiple services that might conflict. Yes, by regular DB interaction I mean connecting to it and running something like `ALTER USER x WITH PASSWORD y`. This is a restriction from DigitalOcean, not Terraform; as an example, TF supports setting the password of an RDS DB instance on AWS